# Returning AJAX responseText from a seperate file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, responsetext

> *This question may have been asked a million times in the past but I am yet to come across a solution. So I ask again, hoping a less
>   aggressive answer like "Look somewhere else" or "Don't repeat
>   questions". If the reader feels the urge to type any of or similar to
>   the aforementioned sentences, I can only request the reader to refrain
>   from doing so and ignore this post completely. Any help is greatly
>   appreciated.*

**The problem**

In my program, an AJAX script works to communicate with a PHP script. There are no syntax errors. The AJAX receives the `responseText` well and alerts it out.

`alert(request.responseText); //this works as desired`

But fails to return it to another function.

`return(request.responseText); //this actually returns undefined`

**The full code**
*Client file*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function createXMLHttp()
    {
        var xmlHttp = null; 
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if(window.ActiveXObject)
        {   
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return xmlHttp;
    }

    function ajax_phprequest(data, php_file)
    {
        var request =  createXMLHttp();
        request.open("POST", php_file, true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send(data);
        request.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (request.readyState == 4)
            {
                document.write(request.responseText);
                return request.responseText; //changed from return(request.responseText;);
            }
        }
    }

    function foo()
    {
        alert(ajax_phprequest("user=defuser&pass=123456","auth.php"));
    }
</script>
</head>
    <input type="button" id="somebutton" value="Call foo()" onclick="foo();" />
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**The full code**
*auth.php file*

```
<?php
    $user;
    $pass;
    if (isset($_POST['user']))  $user = $_POST['user'];
    else
    {
        echo 'err_u_Username is not specified';
        exit();     
    }
    if (isset($_POST['pass']))  $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    else
    {
        echo 'err_p_Password is not specified';
        exit();
    }
    if ($user = 'defuser' && $pass = '123456') echo ('That\'s right!');
    else echo ('That\'s not right!');
?>
```

This can easily be solved by including the code in the same file as the document. But I wish to call the function from a different file and then return it to the file that has `foo()` or the document. Simply, I want the AJAX function to return the responseText without it giving an `undefined' every time. If this has anything to do with synchronization: I want to know of any workarounds against this problem.

Comment: It's not good practice to tell how people should react to your question...

Comment: Just put the value returning in an hidden field and call another function after this and grab the value from that hidden field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gist of it has already been mentioned, but I would like to go into a bit more depth as to why this doesn't work.

You have the following code:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (request.readyState == 4)
    {
        document.write(request.responseText);
        return(request.responseText);
    }
}
```

Basically, you are setting the `onreadystatechange` event to the value of an anonymous function. In that anonymous function, you are returning a value, which won't be returned to the caller of `ajax_phprequest()`, but to the caller of the anonymous function, which is the event system and which doesn't care much about what value is returned.

This happens this way because it all happens asynchronously. In other words, you call `ajax_phprequest()` and all that happens at that moment happens behind the screens. The user can continue working like nothing has happened. However, in the background, the php file is requested and hopefully returned. When that happens, you get to use the contents, but the moment at which you called `ajax_phprequest()` has long since passed.

A proper way would be to use a callback function instead. It could look something like this:

```
function ajax_phprequest(data, php_file, callback)
{
    var request =  createXMLHttp();
    request.open("POST", php_file, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(data);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (request.readyState == 4)
        {
            document.write(request.responseText);
            callback(request.responseText);
        }
    }
}

function foo()
{
    ajax_phprequest("user=defuser&pass=123456","auth.php", function (text)
    {
        alert(text);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the call is ASYNCHRONOUS so you cannot return from stack the usual way, i.e. your `alert(ajax_phprequest("user=defuser&pass=123456","auth.php"));` is evaluated before the ajax response is returned ... you need to use a callback:

```
function callback( text ){
    // something
}

...
if (request.readyState == 4){
    callback( request.responseText );
}
```

Comment: So the callback cannot return the value (i tried and it still returns undefined), but must do whatever that's specified inside it? That will work, but I was hoping for a solution that can return the value to another function to a different file.

Comment: no the callback cannot return the value ... you need to use callback or event dispatcher/listeners - to be precise, the callback can return a value but you won't be able to use it from within a sequential code exactly because of synchronization